# Study the sign of eigenvalues using Law of Inertia

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The book of Linear Algebra and Its Applications by Peter Lax talks about Law of Inertia for positive, negative zero eigenvalues of a linear map. But the book does not present a practice application. For example

$$M = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 5 & 1 & 0\\
5 & 0 & 5 & 0\\
1 & 5 & 0 & 5\\
0 & 0 & 5 & 0
\end{array}\right)$$

I know that $M$ has two positive eigenvalues and two negative eigenvalues, but how to use the Law of Inertia for get this? I mean determine the sign without explicitly calculating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does require some sort of calculation, either completing the square (Lagrange's method) or doing the same thing backwards. Here, $PQ=QP=I.$ We see that the diagonal elements of $D$ are two positive and two negative numbers. Numerically, the eigenvalues, which we are ignoring, are
 $$ -7.672402397924414971791413120, \; \; -3.561373056202417532539267706, \; \; 2.671382004610319545357997188, \; \; 8.562393449516512958972683639$$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 5 & 1 & 0 \\ 
5 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\ 
1 & 5 & 0 & 5 \\ 
0 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
10 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 25 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 4 }{ 5 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
10 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 25 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 4 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 5 & 1 & 0 \\ 
5 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\ 
1 & 5 & 0 & 5 \\ 
0 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

======================================================================

Algorithm discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 5 & 1 & 0 \\ 
5 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\ 
1 & 5 & 0 & 5 \\ 
0 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 5 & 1 & 0 \\ 
5 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\ 
1 & 5 & 0 & 5 \\ 
0 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
10 & 5 & 6 & 0 \\ 
5 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\ 
6 & 5 & 0 & 5 \\ 
0 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
10 & 0 & 6 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 2 & 0 \\ 
6 & 2 & 0 & 5 \\ 
0 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
10 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 &  -  \frac{ 18 }{ 5 }  & 5 \\ 
0 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 4 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
10 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 2 & 5 \\ 
0 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 4 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
10 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 25 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 5 & 1 & 0 \\ 
5 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\ 
1 & 5 & 0 & 5 \\ 
0 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
10 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 25 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 4 }{ 5 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
10 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 25 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 4 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 5 & 1 & 0 \\ 
5 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\ 
1 & 5 & 0 & 5 \\ 
0 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: I have two questions: first, how do you find the matrix $P$ without calculate the eigenvalues? (I mean because I don't know how to do that). Second, after find the matrix $P$, what is the relevance of the Law of Inertia? Since you find explicitly who are the eigenvalues.

Comment: @Greg, no, those are not the eigenvalues!  I find $P$ as a product of "elementary" matrices. As each elementary matrix has an easy inverse, this allows me to construct $P^{-1}$ as well. I will put the whole business in the answer.